# store results as tuples of large array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

d0 = np.random.random_integers(10, 12, (5,5))
d1 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5,5))
d2 = np.random.random_integers(4, 6, (5,5))
d3 = np.random.random_integers(7, 9, (5,5))
d4 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5,5))
d5 = np.random.random_integers(13, 15, (5,5))

data = np.array([d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5])

data = data.reshape(6,25)


data = data.T
```

Wanted to calculate minima column wise:

```
minimas =[]
for x in data:
    minima = (signal.argrelmin(x, axis=0))
    minimas.append(x[minima])
```

Wanted to store results in the shape of original data.

```
print np.array(minimas).reshape([5,5])
```

BUT

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

Is not it possible to store results as tuples of large array?
Would appreciate to know if there is more efficient way of solving this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to find? Minimum value of each column ?

Comment: yes, minimum values values of each column

Comment: i want to store it as tuples so that i can separate the minima values belonging to eachcolumn because eachcolumn may have different numbers of minima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert each item to list and then using list slicing you can index whatever values you need.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

d0 = np.random.random_integers(10, 12, (5, 5))
d1 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5, 5))
d2 = np.random.random_integers(4, 6, (5, 5))
d3 = np.random.random_integers(7, 9, (5, 5))
d4 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5, 5))
d5 = np.random.random_integers(13, 15, (5, 5))

data = np.array([d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5])

data = data.reshape(6, 25)

data = data.T

minimas = []
for x in data:
    minima = (signal.argrelmin(x, axis=0))
    minimas.append(x[minima])
tup = list(a.tolist() for a in minimas)
ab = (np.array(tup).reshape(25, 2))
print(ab[0]) #[3 1]
```

Comment: thanks for yourefforts. but there is a difference between minimum value and minima values because minima refers to minimum points of a curve and in my question there are two minima values per each column

Comment: i want to store the values received from the for loop in my question as tuples so that the minima of each column are in separate tuples

Comment: `np.array(tup)` is already `(25,2)`.  No need to reshape, unless it is to `(5,5,2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`minimas` is a list of 25 arrays (each shape `(2,)`).  `np.array(minimas)` has shape `(25,2)`.

```
np.array(minimas).reshape(5,5,2)
```

works.

You could pack `minimas` into an array with `dtype=object`:

```
minarray = np.empty((5,5),dtype=object) # initialize an empty array of 'objects'
minarray[:] = [tuple(m) for m in minimas]
minarray.reshape(5,5)

array([[(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3)],
...
       [(3, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

---

If the arrays in `minimas` differ in size, then the array will automatically have type `object`.

```
minimas[-1] = np.array([1,2,3]) # tweak data so there is some length variation
minimas = [tuple(row) for row in minimas]
np.array(minimas)
```

produces

```
array([(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
       (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 2), (3, 3), (2, 2),
       (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2),
       (1, 2, 3)], dtype=object)  # shape=(25,)
```

which can be `reshape(5,5)`.

If the arrays in `minimas` are all the same length, then `np.array(minimas)` makes an array with a final size 2 dimension.  That's why I had to initialize an `minarray` array of the desired type, and insert `minimas` in it.  This an obscure part of `numpy` that I picked up from answering other SO questions.

Comment: since the number of minimas for each column may vary in the data i am working with and i need to store all the minimas, i was thinking of it toput as tuples. is there another good way of doing it. anyway, i have to store all the computed minimas separate to each column

Comment: i could not understand your code. what is x? is x is same as i used for x in data...???

Comment: I've added some notes.  If the number of minimas differ, then array will automatically have `dtype=object`.  But in your example the number of minimas are all the same, requiring some extra code to produce an array of tuples.